# How to pass a tree selection to another tree selection view in MFC

Tags: mfc, treeview, window, handle

I have two tree view in MFC window application. Tree1 and Tree2
If i select any one item in tree1 and the same one should find and get select in tree2.

My code is like below.
Selecting first tree item and trying to pass the item to Tree2

```
void TreePage::TreeSelHandle(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
   CTreeCtrl m_ctlTree1, m_ctlTree2;
   m_ctlTree1.OnTvnSelTreeItem(pNMHDR, pResult);

   NMHDR nmhdr;
   nmhdr.code = TVN_SELCHANGED;
   nmhdr.hwndFrom = m_ctlTree2.GetSafeHwnd();
   nmhdr.idFrom = IDC_MODELVIEW_TREE2;

  if (m_ctlTree2.GetSafeHwnd())
     m_ctlTree2.OnTvnSelTreeItem(&nmhdr, pResult); 
}
```

TreeSelection code is below.

```
void UITreePageCtrl::OnTvnSelTreeItem(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
   NM_TREEVIEW* pNMTreeView = (NM_TREEVIEW*)pNMHDR;
   CString strTreeText;
   Select(pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem, TVGN_CARET | TVGN_FIRSTVISIBLE | 
   TVGN_DROPHILITE);
   SelectItem(pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem);

   strTreeText = GetItemText(pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem);
   *pResult = 0;
}
```

This is not working. Tree2 selection get failure. GetItemText return null char.
How to fix this.? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The `n` in `Tvn` means *notification*. It's a message posted by the control to inform your code, that an item was selected. You do not select an item by invoking the notification handler. You select an item by sending a [TVM_SELECTITEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tvm-selectitem) message, or calling the MFC equivalent. Apart from that, calling `SelectItem` from the notification handler is an error.

Comment: TVM_SELECTITEM also I tried and it did not worked.